# How can I lazy load objects from CoreData in a List View in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

In the following code I'm loading `Categories` from `CoreData` into a `List` view in SwiftUI but for some reason the view seems a little slow when loading. What would be the best way to laze load objects as they show in the screen. In other words, how can I speed up the load time. If I change the main `VStack` to `LazyVStack` it doesn't display any of the categories.

How can I lazy load objects from CoreData in a List View in SwiftUI?

#### Core Data Entities

> Category
> > Attributes
> >>   name
> >>   image

```
    class CategoryServiceModel: ObservableObject{
            
        let manager: CoreDataManager
        
        @Published var categories: [Category] = []  

        init(coreDataManager: CoreDataManager = .instance){
            self.manager = coreDataManager
            loadCategories()
        }

        func loadCategories(){
            let request = NSFetchRequest<Category>(entityName: "Category")

            let sort = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Category.name, ascending: true)
            request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
            do{
                categories =  try manager.context.fetch(request)
                removeDuplicateCategoriesIfNeeded()
            }catch let error{
                print("Error fetching categories. \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    struct CategoriesView: View {
        @EnvironmentObject private var categorySM: CategoryServiceModel
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack{ 
                    List{
                        ForEach(categorySM.categories, id:\.self) { category in
                                let image = UIImage(data: category.image ?? Data())
                                let imageSize: CGFloat = 35
                                HStack{
                                    if let inputImage = UIImage(data: category.image ?? Data()) {
                                        Image(uiImage: inputImage)
                                            .resizable()
                                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                            .frame(width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
                                            .padding(10)
                                            .clipShape(Circle())
                                            .overlay(Circle().stroke(imageColor, lineWidth: 1))
                                    } 
                                    Text(category.name ?? "")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: `@FetchRequest`

Comment: Hmm, so I would have to mix `MVVM` with `@FetchRequest`.  Is it common to mix the two? Thanks.

Comment: Common who knows, is it the most efficient, yes. You could Frankenstein an NSFetchedResultsController approach but last I tried (before SectionedFetchRequest) it was just a pile of bugs, it isn’t worth the effort. NSFetchedResultsController is a reference type, SwiftUI doesn’t work well with it directly.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into `@FetchRequest`. Last question, isn't the purpose of `LazyVStack` and `LazyHStack` to help with loading objects?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes inside of a ScrollView for Lazy loading Views but the CoreData objects themselves get put into memory in “load categories” with CoreData you get “faulting” it isn’t easy to replicate “faulting” (lazy loading+), that is why using the built in tools is best with CoreData.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: @loremipsum - Would you say that using `@FetchRequest` and a `List` would be the most efficient way to load CoreData objects or at least more efficient than `NSFetchRequest`? So far, `@FetchRequest` feels more natural/native with SwiftUI.

Comment: Probably, I’ve never ran the numbers but probably yes, notice that a big different in between FetchRequest the wrapper and NSFetchRequest is the “listening” part. NSFetchRequest doesn’t listen. But I would try ScrollView and LazyVStack too. List is lazy in newer versions of iOS

Comment: I'm using iOS16 so `List` should be Lazy by default since it looks like that was announced in WWDC 20. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List is already lazy by its nature. It is a UICollectionView under the hood on iOS 16-17, and UITableView on iOS 15.

You don’t need neither VStack nor LazyVStack outside the List. The reason why you can’t see the content when put LazyVStack wrapping your List is because it requires explicit height specified, and proposes 0 as proposed height to its children (VStack proposes all its parent frame further, so you can see all content). So, List thinks it’s located inside the frame with 0 height. You can check that simply by adding frame modifier with some explicit height to the List, just try let’s say 300.

So, in short, List is itself a lazy list (UICollectionView), don’t wrap it into any stack (until you know the real reason of doing so, which is not the case in your example).

Now, regarding the Core Data efficient requests. If you have a large amount of objects to fetch, use fetchBatchSize, it will help you to perform efficient requests.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506558-fetchbatchsize

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the good explanation. I'll look into `fetchBatchSize` and `@FetchRequest` as requested by @lorem ipsum. Thanks again.

Comment: You can go with NSFetchRequest if you want to keep it away from the View as you described. So it’s up to you what to choose and where you get more flexibility. You can try an infinity list pagination if that will help. But that’s another story))

Comment: So far I have tried, `Pagination` and `fetchBatchSize`.  Using Pagination, I cannot make it reload more items smoothly when the List is scrolled, it works but it doesn't feel smooth.  I also tried `request.fetchBatchSize = 10` and no matter the limit, it loads all items into the `List`, I think it has to do with the way `List` works, I believe it needs all IDs at load time.  I still need to try `@FetchRequest` even though it's not what I wanted since it breaks the coding pattern I'm currently using. Maybe I'm not using `Pagination` and `fetchBatchSize` correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @fs_tigre Try to investigate this article https://betterprogramming.pub/demystifying-swiftui-list-responsiveness-best-practices-for-large-datasets-d9719f01b719